# Jquery select a class using the this keyword

Tags: jquery, html

I've a situation in which I have to submit comments whenever a user clicks the #postComment link.

Now with this code the first time comment is submitted successfully but not the second time.I think that is because the jquery is not proper and it is getting confused here $('.comment a').

Now I wanna know how to access these kind of variables using the "this" keyword or any other possible solution.

Each time a comment is submitted the newCommentBox variable is appended to the commentWrapper to generate a new commentBox.

Jquery:

```
 $('.comment a').click(function(){


comment="<pre>"+$('textarea').val()+"</pre>";
newcommentBox="<div class='CommentBox'>"
        +"<div class='dp'><img src='../Images/defaultPic.jpg' width='50' height='50' /></div>"
        +"<div class='name'>Muazzam Ali</div>"
        +"<div class='comment'>"
        +"<textarea cols='70' rows='10'></textarea><br />"
            +"<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='postComment'><img src='../Images/commentbutton.png' height='30' width='90' /></a>"
        +"</div>"
    +"</div>";

$(this).prev().html("");
$(this).hide();

$(this).parent().html(comment);
$('#CommentWrapper').append(newcommentBox);

});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="CommentWrapper">
          <div id="CommentHeading">Comments:</div>
    <div class="CommentBox">
        <div class="dp"><img src="../Images/defaultPic.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
                <div class="name">Muazzam Ali</div>
                <div class="comment">Comment</div>
                </div>

    <div class="CommentBox">
        <div class="dp"><img src="../Images/defaultPic.jpg" width="50" height="50" /></div>
        <div class="name">Muazzam Ali</div>
        <div class="comment">
        <textarea cols="70" rows="10"></textarea><br />
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="postComment"><img src="../Images/commentbutton.png" height="30" width="90" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not adding the comment the second time because you've not added the `click` even handler to the new `a` element that represents the submit comment button. You actually have to add the event handler again, to this newly created element. Or, use jQuery's delegation features, using the `on` method, to have the event handler always added to your `a` element.

Personally, though, this is what I would do instead. Here's the updated JavaScript:

```
$('.comment a').click(function _this (){

    comment = "<pre>"+$('textarea').val()+"</pre>";
    newcommentBox = "<div class='CommentBox'>"
        +"<div class='dp'><img src='../Images/defaultPic.jpg' width='50' height='50' /></div>"
            +"<div class='name'>Muazzam Ali</div>"
            +"<div class='comment'>"
                +"<textarea cols='70' rows='10'></textarea><br />"
                +"<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='postComment'><img src='../Images/commentbutton.png' height='30' width='90' /></a>"
            +"</div>"
        +"</div>";

    $(this).prev().html("");
    $(this).hide();

    $(this).parent().html(comment);
    $('#CommentWrapper').append(newcommentBox);
    $('#CommentWrapper').find(".comment a").click(_this);

});
```

What I'm doing here is naming the function expression you're passing to `$(".comment a").click()` with the name `_this`. This name I've given the function is available **only** inside the function itself. Anytime a comment is made, it attaches itself as the click event handler for the *next* `a` element. And it lets you avoid using event delegation, which *can* incur a performance penalty. (If you care about that sort of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a delegate (Assuming jQuery 1.7)

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".comment a", function(e) {
 // handle event
});
```

Comment: If not 1.7, it's `delegate` FYI :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem can be that you're appending the new button after attaching the callback to the click event.

try replacting the `$(".comment a").click(function()...)` with to following:

`$(".comment a").live("click", function()...);` and it will be attached also to the new ones